# Error building NumPy with MKL on OSX with Python 3.3

Tags: python, c, build, numpy, intel-mkl

### ***Background***

Using a 2012 iMac with a 2nd-gen Core i7 processor, I'm trying to build [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) 1.7.0 (and eventually [SciPY](http://www.scipy.org)) on OSX 10.8.3 linked to the [MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) included in the evaluation versions of Intel's [C++ Composer XE 2013](https://registrationcenter.intel.com/RegCenter/Evalform.aspx?productid=1771) and [Fortran Composer XE 2013](https://registrationcenter.intel.com/RegCenter/Evalform.aspx?productid=1795) for OSX. I am following [this article](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl) on Intel's site (loosely adapted, as it's not very specific in some cases) for settings, compiler flags, etc.

### ***Problem***

Using either:

```
$ python3 setup.py config build --compiler=intelem --fcompiler=intelem
```

or

```
$ python3 setup.py config --compiler=intelem --fcompiler=intelem build_clib --compiler=intelem --fcompiler=intelem build_ext --compiler=intelem --fcompiler=intelem
```

I get the same error:

```
running build_clib
customize IntelEM64TCCompiler
customize IntelEM64TCCompiler using build_clib
running build_ext
customize IntelEM64TCCompiler
customize IntelEM64TCCompiler using build_ext
building 'numpy.core._dummy' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: icc -m64 -march=corei7 -O3 -g -fPIC -fp-model strict -fomit-frame-pointer -openmp -xhost -DMKL_ILP64 -I/opt/intel/mkl/include

compile options: '-Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/src/multiarray -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/src/umath -c'
icc: numpy/core/src/dummymodule.c
icc: command line warning #10121: overriding '-marchcorei7' with '-xhost'
icc -m64 -march=corei7 -O3 -g -fPIC -fp-model strict -fomit-frame-pointer -openmp -xhost -DMKL_ILP64 -I/opt/intel/mkl/include -shared build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/src/dummymodule.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3 -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/_dummy.so
icc: command line warning #10121: overriding '-marchcorei7' with '-xhost'
icc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-shared'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyModule_Create2", referenced from:
      _PyInit__dummy in dummymodule.o
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
icc: command line warning #10121: overriding '-marchcorei7' with '-xhost'
icc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-shared'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyModule_Create2", referenced from:
      _PyInit__dummy in dummymodule.o
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
error: Command "icc -m64 -march=corei7 -O3 -g -fPIC -fp-model strict -fomit-frame-pointer -openmp -xhost -DMKL_ILP64 -I/opt/intel/mkl/include -shared build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/src/dummymodule.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3 -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/_dummy.so" failed with exit status 1
```

My `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` are both:

```
/opt/intel/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/lib:/opt/intel/mkl/lib:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib
```

my `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` is:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks:/Library/Frameworks:/System/Library/Frameworks
```

and my `site.cfg` is:

```
[DEFAULT]
library_dirs = /opt/intel/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/lib:/opt/intel/mkl/lib:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib
include_dirs = /opt/intel/include:/opt/intel/include/intel64:/opt/intel/mkl/include:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m:/opt/local/include:/usr/local/include:/usr/include

[mkl]
library_dirs = /opt/intel/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/lib:/opt/intel/mkl/lib:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib
include_dirs = /opt/intel/include:/opt/intel/include/intel64:/opt/intel/mkl/include:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m:/opt/local/include:/usr/local/include:/usr/include
mkl_libs = mkl_rt
lapack_libs = mkl_lapack
```

Symlinks to `icc` and `ifort` are in `/usr/bin` and are functional. The contents of `dummymodule.c` are available in the numpy repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/dummymodule.c). I'm not a C programmer, so I can't immediately see what's wrong. I've gotten this error using both MacPorts python 3.3.0 (using the above settings) and with the python.org 3.3.0, with settings modified to point to it instead of `/opt/local`.

### ***Plea***

Can anyone help figure this out?

## **EDIT**

I swapped out `-shared` for `-dynamiclib`, and am now getting:

```
building extension "numpy.random.mtrand" sources
C compiler: icc -m64 -O3 -g -fPIC -fp-model strict -fomit-frame-pointer -openmp -xhost -DMKL_ILP64

compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m -c'
icc: _configtest.c
icc -m64 -O3 -g -fPIC -fp-model strict -fomit-frame-pointer -openmp -xhost -DMKL_ILP64 _configtest.o -o _configtest
_configtest
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
building data_files sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_py
copying numpy/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy
copying build/src.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/__config__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy
copying numpy/distutils/intelccompiler.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/distutils
copying build/src.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/distutils/__config__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/distutils
copying numpy/distutils/fcompiler/intel.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/distutils/fcompiler
running build_clib
customize IntelEM64TCCompiler
customize IntelEM64TCCompiler using build_clib
running build_ext
customize IntelEM64TCCompiler
customize IntelEM64TCCompiler using build_ext
building 'numpy.core._dummy' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: icc -m64 -O3 -g -fPIC -fp-model strict -fomit-frame-pointer -openmp -xhost -DMKL_ILP64

compile options: '-Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m -c'
icc: numpy/core/src/dummymodule.c
icc -m64 -O3 -g -fPIC -fp-model strict -fomit-frame-pointer -openmp -xhost -DMKL_ILP64 -dynamiclib build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/src/dummymodule.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3 -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/_dummy.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyModule_Create2", referenced from:
      _PyInit__dummy in dummymodule.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyModule_Create2", referenced from:
      _PyInit__dummy in dummymodule.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
error: Command "icc -m64 -O3 -g -fPIC -fp-model strict -fomit-frame-pointer -openmp -xhost -DMKL_ILP64 -dynamiclib build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/src/dummymodule.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3 -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/_dummy.so" failed with exit status 1
```

So, I get a line that says `failure.` after _configtest (not sure what that's about) and the same error(s) down below. Thoughts?

Comment: The command line in the Intel notes does not use build as parameter the first one uses build_clib, which I would guess matches the error a you want a library whilst your call seams to try to make an executable needing main

Comment: `build` is an alias for `build_clib` and `build_ext`. I ran the exact command recommended and still got the error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> icc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-shared'

Here's a problem. Your compiler is trying to build an executable, even though it's been told to build a shared library. According to the icc documentation, `-shared` is only available on Linux systems. Since yours is a MacOSX system, I think you'd want to use `-dynamiclib` instead.

*edit*: I suspect you're missing a link to pylib, in: `icc -m64 -O3 -g -fPIC -fp-model strict -fomit-frame-pointer -openmp -xhost -DMKL_ILP64 -dynamiclib build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/src/dummymodule.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3 -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/numpy/core/_dummy.so`.

The missing link causes this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyModule_Create2", referenced from:
      _PyInit__dummy in dummymodule.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

You need to add `-lpythonX.Y`, where X.Y represents the version of Python you're linking against. If this file exists, but the linker can't find it, you'll need to tell the linker where it is by using a `-Llink/search/directory` (eg. `-Llib/`) directive. If the file doesn't exist, you need to build it.

Comment: OK, I'll try that when I get home. Do you think that alone is responsible for the build fail? It said it was ignoring the option...

Comment: @MattDMo That is a very significant problem. `-c` is supposed to suppress linking, but the linking isn't being suppressed, and you get an "undefined main" as a result. It could be that the dynamic library being compiled as an application is the cause for the linker not being suppressed. Hence, I'm not sure if it's worth postulating the other linker error I see until you try this. Please, keep me in the loop...

Comment: I will let you know. I'm at work now, and I won't be able to try for another 5-8 hours...\

Comment: Please see my edit to the main question. I switched `-shared` for `-dynamiclib` and still get an error. Mysteriously, the `"_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o` is gone...

Comment: @MattDMo: I don't see what's so mysterious about that. `-shared` does for Linux what `-dynamiclib` does for MacOSX, but `-shared` doesn't work on MacOSX and `-dynamiclib` doesn't work on Linux. If `-shared` had worked, you wouldn't have had the `_main` issue to begin with.

Comment: @MattDMo See my edit for advice on resolving the next issue. I wish I could be more helpful.

Comment: `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib` is in both my `site.cfg` (for numpy) and my `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and the builds didn't work. Will specifying `-L/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib` do anything different? I'll try that again tonight, along with `-lpython3.3` and see if that helps...

Comment: well, I've finally gotten back to this project, and your advice was spot on! Adding `-L/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib -lpython3.3` to the compiler arguments did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you change file numpy-1.7.0/numpy/distutils/intelccompiler.py line 37 to

icc -m64 -fPIC -O3 -g -fPIC -fp-model strict -fomit-frame-pointer -openmp -xhost -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle -DMKL_ILP64

This work for me where i have this compile error before